# Make JWST a synonym of the James Webb Telescope tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have [james-webb-telescope](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/james-webb-telescope), but more people seem to know it as JWST. Making a synonym might help people tag their questions appropriately.

Comment: `+1` Actually I'd like to see `jwst` as the tag with the longer version as the synonym if that's possible. JWST is occurring pretty frequently in posts and is quite recognizable.

Comment: but I'm a little confused, as I always am about tags. Is jwst not already a synonym? https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLZL6.png When I start typing jwst I get the other tag.

Comment: @uhoh Some sneaky mod must have added it already. [It's now a synonym](https://space.stackexchange.com/tags/james-webb-telescope/synonyms)

Comment: It's always okay to answer your own question in Stack Exchange! :-)

Comment: I mod flagged for a [status-completed] tag